# SqlCommand update doesn't update/insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

I don't understand why this code doesn't update my SQL Server table data:

```
string stringcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["devbuild"].ConnectionString;

public void Lastlogin()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(stringcon); //CONNECTION

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd2.Connection = con;

    cmd2.CommandText = "update dbo.team set lastlogin=GETDATE() where email=@email";
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailtextbox.Text);

    con.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

When I press the button "login button", nothing happens, absolutely nothing error, nothing updates..

Call function from button.

```
private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lastlogin();
}
```

Comment: How about don't using `GETDATE()` ? pass `DateTime.Now` as a parameter for `lastlogin` and test it.

Comment: I put             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm:ss"));

Comment: And also doesn't update

Comment: are you sure `emailtextbox.Text` is exist in your DB, it may passed with space `Trim` it, check it before passing.

Comment: Did you debug the code? It is actually executing? Did you check if the event handler is attached to the event of button?

Comment: Try to add `int affectedRows = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();` - and if you debug - what do you see as value for `affectedRows`? This will tell you many rows were affected by the operation of the `cmd2` - in your case, how many were updated. If that number is 0 - then your `UPDATE` just isn't doing anything...

Comment: There is no problem with your code, unless the entered email does not exist in DB which mean no any row affected.

Comment: @Aria Yes, i'm sure.. the email corresponds with the emailtextbox.Text

Comment: what's this statement result? MessageBox.Show($" '{emailtextbox.Text}' ");

Comment: @M.Rezaeyan it's empty.. but why..?

Comment: check your textbox name

Comment: @M.Rezaeyan i checked and it is correct..

Comment: Thanks for help, problem solved.  I put the code in other form and i called the email textbox from login form and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Display the sqlstri goed cmd2.commandtext 
Check if it's what you expected

The problem should be your where clause

Your parameters has to be exact the same as the email field